# Top Nav Menu is not appearing in all pages?

Tags: layout, theme, magento2.2.2

Categories show in Menu When i install the **Magento 2.2.2** v with sample data but when i install by custom theme the menu will disappear in `luma default theme`.

Please help me.

Comment: Did You applied that theme to use as a theme from your design configuration in  your magento? Will you please elaborate your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `app/design/frontend/Vendorname/themename/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` then add this:

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link" name="my-account-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Account</argument>
            <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">110</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\RegisterLink" name="register-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Create an Account</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" name="authorization-link"
                   template="Magento_Customer::account/link/authorization.phtml"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Hello Prince, I have check the file, but unfortunately there is no folder exist which name is layout. Only exist templates and root.phtml.

Comment: You create it, you create `layout` folder inside `app/design/frontend/Vendorname/themename/Magento_Theme/` and then you copy `default.xml`from the original theme and you past it inside this path

Comment: I have tried which you said. but not working.